# unity www download file without extension error

Tags: http, unity-game-engine, web

I want to download a file:

http://192.168.0.184/sandbox/Android/AssetBundles/AssetBundles

error message:

> HTTP error 404.3 - Not Found

AssetBundles is not have a extension. I am trying to add a extension like *.txt, .xml,.json,.java* and it's works well. But *.abc,.u3d* is not working.

So what is cause that?

Answer (score 0):

There's probably something wrong with your web server setup.

It probably doesn't allow downloads of URLs that don't have an extension.

What web server are you using?

Comment: bug fixed. I use IIS server window 10 for test. just need to add some MIME type on network settings.